# How to add nested complex property with filtering to Vaadin 7 Grid?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I doing a Vaadin (7.10) app, and in some view, I would need to add an "special" nested property into the container. For the sake of the application, we're using `BeanItemContainer` and Grid. I have some class that stores a `List` of another POJO(s), and I would need to use one property inside those second POJO to filter the grid. A basic example of the config would be:

```
public class A {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    //There are too getters and setters for this two properties
}

public class B { //This class stores a list of As
    private String name;
    private List<A> list;
    //Getters and setters too
}
```

These are my two basic classes, which I use to store data. The Vaadin code to show data would be:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
BeanItemContainer<B> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(B.class);

//////////////
container.addNestedContainerProperty("list.property1"); 
//This OBVIOUSLY doesn't work, because property1 is not part of List
/////////////

grid.setColumns("name");
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

So, my question is:
**Is possible to show in `Grid` this** *`property1`* **without changing from `BeanItemContainer`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a job for a generated property.

BUT: it still requires changing from `BeanItemContainer` or more detailed it requires wrapping it. Anyway it was not a problem when i did it (years ago).

For this you need `GeneratedPropertyContainer`. It is a wrapper for other containers that need generated properties added.

```
GeneratedPropertyContainer container =
    new GeneratedPropertyContainer(yourBeanItemContainer);
```

Add generated properties to that container

```
container.addGeneratedProperty("property1"
   ,new PropertyValueGenerator<String>() { ... });
```

Above mentiond `PropertyValueGenerator` should then return `String` that you possibly choose from some pojo `A`.

[Vaadin API for PropertyValueGenerator](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.7/7.7.10/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/util/PropertyValueGenerator.html)

Update considering filtering: `PropertyValueGenerator` overrides method

```
modifyFilter(Container.Filter filter)
```

> Return an updated filter that should be compatible with the underlying
>   container.

For example: if you just pick the first pojo `A` from list and its `property1` the you could implement this to make the filter to filter out all `B`a whose first `A`s `property1` does not match.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that generated columns doesn't allow filtering, and this is a **must have** as stated in the answer. I will edit it to show more emphasys on it.

Comment: @Shirkam Ok, i have to dig some old project. I have a feeling that this was solved somehow. Was it so that if you use `GeneratedPropertyContainer.addContainerFilter` it throws `UnsupportedFilterException` or why it is not allowed?

Comment: Yup, it throws `UnsupportedFilterException`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that, wish I could upvote you twice

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @pirho's answer, which seemed brilliant to me, there's another possibility:

You can create a *derivated* list in `B` (if you have access to it) of the properties you want to filter like this:

```
public class B {
    //Other already declared properties
    private List<String> derivatedStringList;

    //Here you declare getters and setters
    public void setList(List<A> l) {
        this.list = l;
        this.derivatedStringList = l.stream()
                .map(a -> a.getProperty1())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //Only declare getter, because it's a -->generated<-- property 
    public List<String> getDerivatedStringList() {
        return derivatedStringList;
    }
}
```

And then use it in your `Grid`, filters... Wherever you want.

Comment: Great solution in simplicity. The only con is that you need to touch entity or create a wrapper class for it.

Comment: @pirho I know it. But if you don't want to mess overriding methods you don't know how they work like `modifyFilter`, it's a great workarround. I will try both, thought.